# Code Assembly language in 64-bit

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

I want to know if there is some program that allows me to compile my assembly code for a 64 bit processor.

By now I'm using RTM, TASM and TLINK but those are for 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from intel:

> Assemblers
>   An Internet search reveals x64-capable assemblers such as the Netwide Assembler NASM, a NASM rewrite called YASM, the fast Flat Assembler FASM, and the traditional Microsoft MASM. There is even a free IDE for x86 and x64 assembly called WinASM. Each assembler has varying support for other assemblers' macros and syntax, but assembly code is not source-compatible across assemblers like C++ or Java* are.
>
> For the examples below, I use the 64-bit version of MASM, ML64.EXE, freely available in the platform SDK. For the examples below note that MASM syntax is of the form Instruction Destination, Source

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly

I found YASM here which has 32-bit and 64-bit flavors
http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html

and NASM here:
http://www.nasm.us/

Comment: Thanx you so much. you just helped so much!!!!  
i would give you some up-vote but i cant =(